# Button text appears at the cost of knowing which answer was clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

The code runs fine, but the problem I'm having is that the text box that is suppose to go onto of my answer buttons is behind the button itself... however, if I change two lines of code around, the answer validation code doesn't pick up the which answer was clicked (it returns undefined). This is infuriating!

Look for the line "//INSERT HERE." If I take the line, "var answerField:TextField = createText(answer,answerFormat,answerSprite,0,0,450);" and put it there instead, it returns the right answers (doesn't return undefined), but I can no longer see the text. I've included the createText function as well.

Ideas?

```
    private function askQuestion()
    {
        trace("asking question...");

        // prepare new question sprite
        qBox = new QuestionBox();
        questionSprite = new Sprite();
        gameSprite.addChild(qBox);
        gameSprite.addChild(questionSprite);
        qBox.x = 240;
        qBox.y = 45;

        // create text field for question
        var question:String = dataXML.item[questionNum].question;
        questionField = createText(question,questionFormat,questionSprite,120,30,250);

        // create sprite for answers, get correct answer and shuffle all
        correctAnswer = dataXML.item[questionNum].answers.answer[0];
        trace("----" + correctAnswer + "----");
        answers = shuffleAnswers(dataXML.item[questionNum].answers);

        // put each answer into a new sprite with a circle icon
        answerSprites = new Sprite();

        for (var i:int=0; i<answers.length; i++)
        {
            trace("generating answers...");
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0 :
                    column = 135;
                    row = 150;
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    column = 135;
                    row = 260;
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    column = 340;
                    row = 150;
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    column = 340;
                    row = 260;
                    break;
            }
            var answer:String = answers[i];
            var answerSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            //INSERT HERE
            var button:Button = new Button();

            answerSprite.x = column;
            answerSprite.y = row;

            // make it a button;
            answerSprite.addChild(button);
            var answerField:TextField = createText(answer,answerFormat,answerSprite,0,0,450);
            answerSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickAnswer);
            answerSprite.buttonMode = true;
            answerSprites.addChild(answerSprite);
        }
        trace("answers generated!");
        questionSprite.addChild(answerSprites);
        trace("question asked!");
        trace(":::awaiting user input:::");
    }
```

createText function:

```
public function createText(text:String, tf:TextFormat, sprite:Sprite, x,y: Number, width:Number):TextField
    {
        var tField:TextField = new TextField();
        tField.x = x;
        tField.y = y;
        tField.width = width;
        tField.wordWrap = true;
        tField.multiline = true;
        tField.selectable = false;
        tField.defaultTextFormat = tf;
        tField.text = text;
        sprite.addChild(tField);
        return tField;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inserting `answerSprite.addChild(button);` AFTER you make that method call.

Try putting that ABOVE the INSERT HERE, and you'll be fine.

i.e.

```
        var answerSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var button:Button = new Button();
        // make it a button;
        answerSprite.addChild(button);
        var answerField:TextField = createText(answer,answerFormat,answerSprite,0,0,450);
            answerSprite.x = column;
            answerSprite.y = row;
```

Comment: What doesn't work? You don't see the answerField or the validation doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry. No validation. My trace is reporting back "undefined" when it returns "event.currentTarget.getChildAt(0).text;"

Comment: Ok do me a favor and trace event.currentTarget it's possible the target of the event handler isn't necessarily the "answer".

Comment: Also, trace out what's at getChildAt(0)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to give the button a name, then use that name to identify the button.